# Moderator tools not showing tab menu in all cases.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm not sure whether this happens on SOFU since I don't have the rep there, but on most pages, I can see all tabs, but on the flags page I only see that page's tab. This makes navigation a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30336/tabs-missing-for-flags-page-in-the-tools-section)

Comment: Congrats on hitting 10k-for-betas (tm)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise that, as I said, I don't have 10k rep anywhere else.

Comment: @Arda, it's kinda fun... not now that you're alone so your votes to delete will fade away slowly, but seeing flagged posts is usually entertaining (at least on meta.so)

Comment: I was just thinking about that... the ability to cast non-binding delete votes is pretty worthless while you are the only one who can.

Comment: You guys are making me feel lonely. :-( Hurry up with that rep Juan.

Comment: This post made no sense to me for the longest time... till today.